# How I need to work with the virtual function "what()"?

Tags: c++, exception, polymorphism, virtual-functions

given a class `Stack` (for example) :

```
class Stack {
    // ...
    class Exception : public std::exception {};
    class Full : public Exception {};
    class Empty : public Exception {};
};
```

Let's look about the next function `f` (for example) :

```
void f() {
    try {
        Stack s(100); // Only for the example. 
    } catch (Stack::Full& e) {
        cerr << "Not enough room";
    } catch (Stack::Exception& e) {
        cerr << "Error with stack";
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

In the case it going to the last `catch` what will be the output?
I need to declare about `what()` function in `Exception` class for that working?

Comment: You should throw something, otherwise nothing to catch.

Comment: @liliscent: how do you know that `Stack s(100);` doesn't throw?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Based on posted code.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I am don't, but my question it's about `what()` function, what will be the output from `e.what()`?

Comment: `what` is a virtual method of `std::exception` class that you can override in your exception class to supply whatever text you want. That is what exception classes deriving from `std::exception` typically do.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo It depends on what type of std::exception it is

Comment: @liliscent I ask about the case that it's going to the last catch, what will be the output from `e.what()`.

Comment: The output will be whatever that specific `std::exception` subclass returns from its `what` overload.  It depends on the actual type of exception caught and the specific information supplied when it was thrown.

Comment: @VTT So, if I understand correct, I need to implement for function `const char* what() const override;` in `class Exception` ?

Comment: Yes. Without that it will print something default.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Yes you have to overload it if you derive from std::exception

Comment: @VTT And it's known what is this "default value"?

Comment: It is implementation-defined if I remember correctly. Why don't you test it yourself to see what it actually prints?

Comment: @VTT Only for be certain, I need to add it only to `class Exception` ? it's will be correct to add it to other class (`Full` or `Empty`) - what is preferred?

Comment: Typically each exception class overrides `what` method. Though it does not really matter.

Comment: @VTT Now I see this declaration `virtual const char* what() const throw()` that someone wrote in his class - it's not need to be `const char* what() const override` ?

Comment: Effect will be the same though second variant is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual `what()` method of a `std::exception` is a nice way to supply a meaningful message to your exceptions and a good cause to always create own exceptions based on `std::exception`.

The very nice thing with this approach is that it's a standardized part of the STL. The STL exceptions return meaningful messages in `what()`.
And this also means, if you would use the socket code somewhere within your `Stack`, you would catch it with your `catch (std::exception& e)` and can e.g. print out the error message without knowing deeper details about the exceptions.

In opposite to that, the non-standardized methods are obviously only available if you explicitly catch an exception of a specific known type.

In terms of your example this means, that you could create your exceptions like this:

```
class Stack {
    // ...
    class Exception : public std::exception {
        virtual const char* what() override { return "Unspecified stack error"; }
    };
    class Full : public Exception {
        virtual const char* what() override { return "Stack is full"; }
    };
    class Empty : public Exception {
        virtual const char* what() override { return "Stack is empty"; }
    };
};
```

You then in your try/catch would only need to catch `std::exception`:

```
void f() {
    try {
        Stack s(100); // Only for the example. 
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Since your exceptions are based on `std::exception`, and you override the `virtual const char* what()`, you will get your messages in the catch clause.

Comment: (regarding the edit suggestion): Why do you want to remove the `virtual` from the functions? Although overridden, they stay virtual. And I think it's always a good indicator to mark overridden functions still `virtual` (Although not strictly necessary and already marked with the `override` keyword)